# JSF selectOneButton with ajax update lost value

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 3.2 with Apache Myfaces 2 on WebSphere Application Server 8.

I have a form, where you can select 2 different view by changing a selectOneButton.

When I use this button without ajax behavior (submit with command button) then the value change works fine.

But when I use something like this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panel header="Panel" toggleable="true" closable="true" id="pan1">
            <p:panel header="Options" toggleable="true" collapsed="true" id="pan2">
                <p:panelGrid style="width:100%; text-align:center;" id="pan3">
                    <p:row>
                        <!-- some outputLabels -->

                        <p:column rowspan="2" style="width:130px;">
                            <p:splitButton value="Show" action="#{ graph.update }"
                                update=":form" id="splitbtn">
                                <p:menuitem value="Update 2"
                                    action="#{ graph.update2 }"
                                    update=":form" />
                            </p:splitButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneButton id="btn1"
                                value="#{ bean.val }">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="lbl1" itemValue="1" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="lbl2" itemValue="2" />
                                <p:ajax event="change"
                                    update=":firstChartForm" />
                            </p:selectOneButton>
                        </p:column>

                        <!--  more coloumns -->
                    </p:row>
                  </p:panel>
                  <!-- more content -->
             </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Then the value of bean.val is empty when I change the button and update the form with ajax.
(Logger in setter method prints 2 times empty value).

Why is the value empty?

Comment: Do you have scope of your `bean` at least `ViewScope` or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a PrimeFaces selectOneButton Bug. Fixed with PrimeFaces 3.4

Link to Issue 3767 in Issue Tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3767

This was fixed in version 3.4 of PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

Every time that you have such a behavior, means that some updates don't specified correctly. try to use update="@form" overall.
it is a little uncommon to use SelectOneButton for this purpose, you can use TabView alternatively to achieve this.

Comment: I tried - but nothing changed. Its only 1 colum which is rendered or not, so I thought I can do this with a selectOneButton